# File Browser in Oracle Apex Application

Tags: oracle, jquery-plugins, oracle-apex

I am working on an application in which I need a file browser to attach files. To achieve this I am using

```
jquery.fileupload[plug-in]
```

as item type. However, it is giving this error:

```
ORA-06550: line 4, column 50: PLS-00201: identifier 'PLUGIN_JQUERY_FILE_UPLOAD.PLUGIN_RENDER' must be declared ORA-06550: line 4, column 1: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Help!

Comment: That error means that your code is trying to be interpreted as SQL or PL/SQL; whereas I suspect it's javascript. Anyway, I wouldn't use that for this purpose. I'd use Apex's built in file upload item type.

Comment: No, it's not javascript. PLUGIN_JQUERY_FILE_UPLOAD.PLUGIN_RENDER function used to render plugin in PL/SQL. But i think your plugin not correctly installed. Give more info. Apex version, how do you installed plugin, how do you use it, and more...

Comment: apex_error_code: WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN.RUN_PLSQL_ERR
ora_sqlcode:-6550
ora_sqlerrm:ORA-06550: line 4, column 50: PLS-00201: identifier 'PLUGIN_JQUERY_FILE_UPLOAD.PLUGIN_RENDER' must be declared ORA-06550: line 4,column 1: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
component.type:APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_ITEMS
component.id:4457814698007562
component.name:P57_FILE
error_backtrace:
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1815
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL", line 973
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL", line 999
ORA-06512: at "APEX_040200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 806
ORA-06512: at "APEX_040200.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 1025

Comment: This full error stack doesn't help. The primary error in it is the one in your post aswell. We did not ask for this full stack. Read what @NoGotnu has written: it is obviously a PLUGIN error. What plugin did you use and do you have a link to it? What apex version are you on? Why is the default file browse item insufficient?

Comment: I am using Application Express 4.2.0.00.27. my plugins are properly installed. default file browser item running well but i want multiple selection that is why i am trying to use this JQUERY PLUGIN.

Comment: Are you sure that plugin installed correctly? Where have you declared this function `PLUGIN_JQUERY_FILE_UPLOAD.PLUGIN_RENDER` ?

Comment: SORRY, that plsql file which i have to compile in SQL DEVELOPER is not compiled correctly. Its working now..